# How to remove parent iframe by cliking in a button inside it?

Tags: javascript, php

I have an iframe and a button to click inside it. How can I remove this iframe by cliking in this button?

example:

```
  <iframe src="link"><button onlick="removeparent()"></iframe>
```

Is there an way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
      <iframe id="demo" src="http://www.microsmsm.com/"></iframe>
      <button onClick="removeparent()">Remove Iframe</button>
      <script>
    function removeparent(){
        document.getElementById("demo").remove();
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `button` outside of the `iframe`. You can't have it inside.

```
<iframe src="link"></iframe>
<button onclick="removeparent();"></button>
```

Comment: It need to be inside.. is there anyway to do that?

Comment: No you can't, why do you need it inside anyway?